# Layout is behind Navigation bar (out of screen)

Tags: android, layout

I created a Basic-Activity and have the activity_main which includes the content_main. But at the Design-Screen I can see, that the included content_main starts below the toolbar and ends behind the navigationbar. I think that the Included layout is as high as the full screen and not as high as the space between toolbar and the end of screen. What can I do?
[Screenshot of Designscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OSapp.png)

**Activity_Main**

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.htlhl.kellergassen_app.MainActivity"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/KG_orange">

            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/HomeActivity"
                style="@style/Toolbartitle_KG" />

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**Content_Main**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background2"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.htlhl.kellergassen_app.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main"
    android:id="@+id/rl_main">


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="false"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:onClick="here">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/Kellergassenlogo"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/ButtonKellergasse"
            android:onClick="toKellerkatze"
            android:src="@drawable/kk_logo" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnToKellergasse"
            android:layout_width="180dp"
            android:layout_height="36dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
            android:background="@drawable/roundbutton"
            android:onClick="toKellerkatze"
            android:text="@string/ButtonKellergasse"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/Routenlogo"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:layout_gravity="top|bottom|center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/ButtonRoute"
            android:onClick="toRouten"
            android:src="@drawable/routenlogo" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnToRouten"
            android:layout_width="180dp"
            android:layout_height="36dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
            android:background="@drawable/roundbutton"
            android:onClick="toRouten"
            android:text="@string/ButtonRoute"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnParse"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="parse"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:background="@color/KG_green"
        android:onClick="startParsing"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_bottom_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="3">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <fragment
                android:id="@+id/fragmentChooseLang"
                android:name="com.htlhl.kellergassen_app.FragmentLanguage"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvChooseLang"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/german_flag"
                android:text="@string/chooseLanguage"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnToImpressum"
            style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/ButtonImpressum"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The Layout named "layout_bootom_main" is not shown, because it is layout_alignParentBottom and the parents end is out of screen.

Answer (score 1):

You can add scroll view in content_main as parent view for both linear layouts.

```
<RelativeLayout>
   <ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

       <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <!-- Add your linear layouts here -->

       </LinearLayout>
   </ScrollView>
</RelativeLaout>
```

And while designing in android studio try to preview the design with device having more hight

Comment: But I want that everythin fits on screen. The include Tags size is bigger than the screen, but it should end above the navbar

Comment: I didn't exactly understand @Goetti.

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap everything inside a scrollview like this:

```
<RelativeLayout
......>
   <ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
```

<-! All the layout children in here-->

```
   </ScrollView>
</RelativeLaout>
```

Comment: Thats possible, but when I come back to the Main Activity, the Layout which was behind the Navbar when "onCreate" is called, is then above the navbar, so then the screen is measured right...